# Converting 10e-3 to decimal

Tags: php

This line:

```
echo (float)10e-3;
```

is returning:

```
0.01
```

But I expected it to return `0.001` as said here:

http://www.uky.edu/~garose/sciencenotation.htm

```
1/1000 = 0.001 = 1 x 10e-3
```

Comment: You should notice that 10e-3 is 10 * 10^-3 that is 0.01 and it is not the same as pow(10,-3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are using is called the `E-notation` [see wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation).

It has a format of `MeN` and it means `M * 10^N`.
In your case it's

```
10 * 10 ^ -3 = 10 / 1000 = 0.01
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no error here,

```
10^(-3) = 0.001
```

So

```
10*0.001 = 0.01
```

Your website is saying that :

```
1/1000 = 0.001 = 1 x 10e-3
```

Which is true, but you are not doing 1 x 10e-3 but 10x10e-3